# Multiple rows being created when one row should be generated

Tags: php, mysql

I have a comments feature on my social networking site. The idea is that when a user clicks on the `comments` link printed for each message, a list of existing messages are displayed as well as a form to add your own comment. I.e.

[image]

But, when a user adds a comment, it adds the comment to all the users posts. For example Ronda has two posts. If I add a comment to Ronda's post "Hello" (in image), the comment will also be displayed for the post with the id completely different and two rows will be generated in my `user_comments` table. If a user has more posts, I.e. Alice has 10 posts, if I add a comment to one of them, the same comment will be displayed for all 10 posts (and 10 new rows in db).

I don't understand why it is happening. It use to work fine before, and I haven't changed anything (from what I remember). Here is my approach:

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts WHERE added_by='$user' AND shared ='yes' ORDER BY id DESC");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $thought_id      = $row['id'];
    $message_content = $row['message'];
    $date_of_msg     = $row['post_details'];
    $thoughts_by     = $row['added_by'];
    $attachent       = $row['attachment'];
    $shared          = $row['shared'];

echo "  <div class='message_wrapper'>

        // the actual post will be displayed here, as well as the comment link.

        </div>";

// this is where each comment is displayed 
            echo "<div id='toggleComment$thought_id' class='new_comment'>";
            if ($account_type2 == "user"){
                // displaying the add new comment form ....
                echo "
                    <form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <textarea id='txtarea' name='comment_msg' cols='80' maxlength='180' placeholder=' add your comment...'></textarea> 
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id='send' type='submit' name='send_comm' value='Share'/> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                         </table> <hr/>
                    </form>";
            }
            while($comment = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($get_comm)) { 
                $comment_id = $comment['id'];
                $comment_body = $comment['body_of_msg']; 
                $comment_posted_to = $comment['comment_posted_to']; 
                $comment_posted_by = $comment['comment_posted_by']; 
                $removed = $comment['comment_removed']; 

            $name_q = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$comment_posted_by'");
            while($roww = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($name_q)) {   
                $post_firstname = $roww['first_name'];
                $post_lastname = $roww['last_name'];

            echo " 
            <div class='new_comm' id='thoughtId".$thought_id."-childId".$comment['id']."'> 
                <br/><b><a href = 'profile_page/$comment_posted_by'> $post_firstname $post_lastname</a></b>: $comment_body "; ?><?php 
                } 
            }
            echo "</div>";
/*************************/
    // here is where I process a new comment, and send it to the database.
    // sending comments to database 
    $comment = htmlentities(trim(strip_tags(@$_POST['comment_msg'])));
    $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $comment);

    // if button is pressed, do this...
    if(isset($_POST['send_comm'])){
        if (!empty ($comment)){
            $insert_comment = mysqli_query ($connect, "INSERT INTO user_comments VALUES ('','$comment','$username','$user','0','$thought_id')");
            header ("Location: /profile_page/$user");
        } 
    }       
/****************************/
}// while closed

?>
```

**Edit**:

I think I know what the issue is, but do not know how to resolve it.

The problem is that `if(isset($_POST['send_comm'])){` processing is done in the while loop which displays all the posts for a user. However, if I put it outside the while loop, `$thought_id` in that code will be undefined. I have tried this approach:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $thought_id      = $row['id'];

    // if button is pressed, do this...
    if(isset($_POST['send_comm'])){
        if (!empty ($comment)){
            $insert_comment = mysqli_query ($connect, "INSERT INTO user_comments VALUES ('','$comment','$username','$user','0','$thought_id')");
            header ("Location: /profile_page/$user");
        } 
    }
}
```

But no comment is added to the post (no row is generated, INSERT query not executed).

Comment: In the query to select the comments add a filter for the post id. Now you are selecting all user's posts

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: @LelioFaieta - I assume you are referring to the `$get_comm` query? In which case I do - `$get_comm = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_comments WHERE post_id='$thought_id' ORDER BY id DESC");`

Comment: Take a step back and go through your code logically. Look at what each line does, and think about the effect it will have. For example, why are you making a `while` loop? Why are you checking for `$_POST`? I hope the answer to those two questions is not the same.

Comment: @miken32 - I'm guessing you're referring to this while loop in the last code block? And honestly, looking back at it now, I do not know. My thought process was that if I am to put the submit button processing outside the while loop, then I have to somehow get the `$thought_id` of the post the comment is being assigned to.

Comment: That's correct. So you pass it as a form input. There's no reason to have POST handling code in the same file as GET handling code. Everything the POST request needs should be passed to it.

Comment: @miken32 - But that's another issue. You see since I am putting the processing code, and then run `$_GET` i.e. `$getting_thought_id = $_GET['id'];`, I will get undefined errors, seeing as everything is defined within the while loop?